# How can I make sure that the WCF service is always available for everyone?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-hosting

This is my very first time with WCF services and I have some questions about it. I have a project layout which looks like following:

- WCF Project
- Client Project(which references to WCF project as a service reference)

  - I had provided the Http:// address that is created when I run the WCF project as the service address while adding the service reference.
  - Everytime I run the client application, I also run the WCF project to make sure that WCF service is always available when client wants to consume it
  - I know that this is not a sustainable design because having to run WCF project every-time I want to use the WCF service is not going to work out.

Also,

- I am in a team environment and I also want to make sure that when my teammates get the latest code from me they can run the client application without having to worry about the WCF application

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So why not run your service under IIS on a production server that your team can access? How is it currently deployed?

Comment: Have you tried running the WCF application as a service instead of manually? Is the WCF side running from a dedicated server? The teammates, are they running their own version of the WCF application?

Comment: You will have to host your WCF service on IIS or as Windows Service.See here for the details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reviewing general information about WCF service hosting, as a new WCF service developer, you need to consider the following service aspects:

**Instancing**
The instancing behavior (set by using the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode` property) controls how the `InstanceContext` is created in response to incoming messages.

- PerCall: A new instance is created for each client request
- PerSession: A new instance is created for each new client
- Single:  A single instance handles all client requests

Each have pros and cons, so you need to select the proper behavior for your service scenario.

**Concurrency**
Concurrency is the control of the number of threads active in an InstanceContext at any one time. This is controlled by using the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.ConcurrencyMode` with the `ConcurrencyMode` enumeration.

- Single:  One thread processing messages in the instance context at a time
- Multiple : Each service instance can have multiple threads processing messages concurrently.
- Reentrant : Each service instance processes one message at a time, but accepts re-entrant operation calls.

**Throttling**
The `ServiceThrottlingBehavior` class exposes properties that you can use to limit how many instances or sessions are created at the application level. Using this behavior, you can fine-tune the performance of your Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) application.

```
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ThrottledService">
          <serviceThrottling 
             maxConcurrentCalls="n" 
             maxConcurrentInstances="n" 
             maxConcurrentSessions="n" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx